# Syntax for dynamically rendering array element's index value in HTML tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

A collection of objects are found and are sorted on the basis of a unique value

```
@sections = Section.where('id IN (?)', @sections_uniq).to_a
```

This is then meant to be presented in the view as tabs (using foundation), with one tab for each unique value

```
<% @sections.each do |section, index| %>
   <li>
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id='tab<%= index %>' />
```

the index value is necessary to create on tab per unique value.

No version of `<%=`or `#{...}` seems to work.
What is the syntax to generate that index value ( i.e. id='tab0', id='tab1'...) within the quoted value of the HTML tag?

Comment: You need `each_with_index`, since each doesn't yield the index by itself.

Comment: Right, but this still generates `Enumerator:0x007ffb2c1d0d60`type result

Comment: Can you show that result?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="tabs" id='tab#&lt;Enumerator:0x007ffb2cc8dc58&gt;'  />

Comment: And your code in the view, remains the same?

Comment: I have tried versions of `id='tab<%= index %>'` and `id='tab<%= @sections.index %>'`

Comment: @SebastianPalma is right: you must write `id='tab<%= index %>'`

Comment: Been there.  Get `undefined method 'index' for #&lt;Section:0x007ffb2a8a8d38&gt;`

Comment: `@sections` is itself the result of your `Section.where`, that's why you get Enumerator representation. But each_with_index yields the object inside each object, and plus the index, so your attempt `<%= index %>` should work.

Comment: actually the problem is upstream.  Needs to be `.each.with_index`  reference: https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index  rubybull's comment

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @sections.each.with_index do |section, index| %>
```

The collection needs first to be converted [to enumerator. And that can be done via the help of .to_enum, .each, or .map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index)

**update, second alternative**

As pointed out in comments below defining in controller

```
@sections = Section.where('id IN (?)', @sections_uniq)
```

without a suffix, and in the view.

```
<% @sections.each_with_index do |section, index| %>
```

works just as well.

Thus the solution depends on what one will do with the array, aside from the initial case (as described above), within the action.

Comment: What do you get by removing `.to_a` on `@sections`?

Comment: I got the same result using `all` .  Had not thought of removing the array definition suffix...  Removing the suffix and retaining `each_with_index`for invoking the array works as well.

Comment: You can easily use `each_with_index` if `Section.where('id IN (?)', @sections_uniq)` returns a `Section::ActiveRecord_Relation`.